# Mailjet Vars blank array throws error

Tags: php, email, mailjet

```
$array = [
  "low_price_low_stock_goods" => []
]
```

In my mailjet template

```
   {% for item in var:low_price_low_stock_goods %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ item.good_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

error is now No value for "var:low_price_low_stock_goods"

Comment: `"low_price_low_stock_goods" => []`  it means your `"low_price_low_stock_goods"` index have empty array.since it's an empty array so how can you get any value from it?

Comment: @AlivetoDie So my for loop should not execute or i want to check if array is not empty then only run for loop.

Comment: `check if array is not empty then only run for loop`->this is what you have to do

Comment: @AlivetoDie but how I do check array is not empty in mailjet template?

Comment: @aridjar Have you any idea in that?

Comment: Hi from Mailjet. When you are trying to loop on array, which is empty, it is not skipped, but an error is thrown instead - it's the current behavior. We are aware of the troubles it causes and will work on fixing it in future. At the moment, there is no really useful workaround.

Comment: @Zhivko ok fine what i am doing i am passing then yes, no from my php in mjml. So can you give me code if condition yes then only for loop run.

if my if condition false and for loop inside loop still i got error.

Answer (score 1):

As I [answered you on Github](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/676#issuecomment-301730504) Ricky:  it's a known issue on Mailjet's templating language side, sorry for that. To avoid it, just pass a valid object in the API call for the `low_price_low_stock_goods value`. This will work:

```
{
  item.good_name: "",
  item.value: "",
  item.count: ""
}
```