# mailjet mjml blank array throws error

Tags: email, mailjet, mjml

mailjet mjml blank array throws error

In my var:low_price_low_stock_goods is empty array for loop should not execute but it throws error: No value for "var:low_price_low_stock_goods"

```
{% for item in var:low_price_low_stock_goods %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered on [Github](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/676#issuecomment-301730504) and your [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000574/4517745): it's a known issue on Mailjet's templating language side, sorry for that. To avoid it, just pass a valid object in the API call for the `low_price_low_stock_goods` value. This will work:

```
{
  item.good_name: "",
  item.value: "",
  item.count: ""
}
```